# -fpermissive option in codeblocks. Where do I put that "-fpermissive" option?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
```

I need help with this code. My compiler keeps asking me to use the -fpermissive option but I don't know where to input it. I've pasted the code below and the error that is shown.

```
using namespace std;

int cx = 0, cy = 0;

double x =0, y=0,  r = 5;


int main(){

ofstream myfile;

myfile.open("dingo.txt");

for(int g =0 ; g <= 360; g++)

//find x and y

//Get points of a circle.

x = cx + r * cos(g);

y = cy + r * sin(g);

//This is what pops up below:

//In function int main()':

//Error: name lookup of 'g' changed for ISO 'for' scoping [-fpermissive]

//note: (if you use '-fpermissive' G++ will accept your code)

//where should I enter the required option?

myfile << "X: " << x << "; Y: " << y <<endl;

myfile.close();

return 0;

}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `-fpermissive`, instead you should fix the error in your code.

Comment: Why do you want to use `-fpermissive` rather than fixing you code?

Comment: Even if you did use `-fpermissive`, the code would not do what you want it to.

Answer (score 6):

You can add more compiler flags under `"Other Options"` in `"Settings"` > `"Compiler"`

[image]

Although I think you should fix your code first. For example, `std::sin` and `std::cos` accepts radians, not degrees. You also need braces around your `for` statement.

```
for(int g =0 ; g <= 360; g++) {
    //code here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks especially for the radians part. I've never known that till now.

Answer (score 1):

*Don't* use `-fpermissive`.

It means "I really, really know what I'm doing here, so please shut up" and is never, ever a good beginner's option.

And in this case, "g++ will accept your code" means "g++ will not complain about your code, but the bugs will still be there, and you will waste many hours looking for them since the code compiled without so much as a warning".

Indenting your code properly exposes the problem:

```
int main(){
    int cx = 0, cy = 0;
    double x = 0, y = 0, r = 5;
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("dingo.txt");
    for(int g = 0 ; g <= 360; g++)
        x = cx + r * cos(g);
    y = cy + r * sin(g);  // <--- Here it is.
    myfile << "X: " << x << "; Y: " << y <<endl;
    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

It's clear that the indicated line uses `g`, which is the loop variable.
In olden times, the scope of a variable declared in a `for`-loop was actually the scope enclosing the loop (the `main` function, in your case).
This was later changed so the scope of a loop variable is limited to the *inside* of the loop, but since there is a lot of legacy code that relies on the old rules, compilers provide a way to enable the obsolete behaviour.

What you intended was probably this:

```
for(int g = 0; g <= 360; g++)
{
    x = cx + r * cos(g);
    y = cy + r * sin(g);
    myfile << "X: " << x << "; Y: " << y <<endl;
}
```

(which is *also* wrong, because `sin` and `cos` use radians, not degrees - but I'll leave that problem as an exercise.)