# Finding process ID and base address using winapi

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm writing a program in Code::Blocks that would simply print application's process ID and base address. The PID is found correctly but I'm having difficulties with base address also I'm using GNU GCC Compiler (x64). My guess is that the error lies in `HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, procId);` because it returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. But still I can't resolve this problem. The IDE doesn't show any error or warnings. GetLastError() returns 5 (Access Denied)

Console output:
`Process ID = 2656
INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE returned
BaseAddr = 0`

And this is full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <string.h>

DWORD GetProcId(const char* procName)
{
    DWORD procId = 0;
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (hSnap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        PROCESSENTRY32 procEntry;
        procEntry.dwSize = sizeof(procEntry);

        if (Process32First(hSnap, &procEntry))
        {
            do
            {
                if (lstrcmpi(procEntry.szExeFile, procName) == 0) {
                    procId = procEntry.th32ProcessID;
                    break;
                }
            } while (Process32Next(hSnap, &procEntry));

        }
    }
    CloseHandle(hSnap);
    return procId;
}

uintptr_t GetModuleBaseAddress(DWORD procId, const char* modName)
{
    uintptr_t modBaseAddr = 0;
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, procId);
    if (hSnap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        MODULEENTRY32 modEntry;
        modEntry.dwSize = sizeof(modEntry);
        if (Module32First(hSnap, &modEntry))
        {
            do
            {
                if (!_stricmp(modEntry.szModule, modName))
                {
                    modBaseAddr = (uintptr_t)modEntry.modBaseAddr;
                    break;
                }
            } while (Module32Next(hSnap, &modEntry));
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE returned" << std::endl;
    }
    CloseHandle(hSnap);
    return modBaseAddr;
}

int main()
{
    DWORD procId = GetProcId("Game.exe");

    std::cout << "Process ID = " << procId << std::endl;

    uintptr_t baseAddr = GetModuleBaseAddress(procId, "Game.exe");

    std::cout << "BaseAddr = " << baseAddr << std::endl;

    std::getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [CreateToolhelp32Snapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-createtoolhelp32snapshot): *"If the function fails, it returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. **To get extended error information, call [GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror).**"*

Comment: It returns 5 after calling CreateToolhelp32Snapshot so access denied. But I'm running as admin.

Comment: 5 translates to [ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-).

Comment: I know it's access denied but it doesn't help me in any way.

Comment: It may not solve your immediate problem, but it helps you understand the failure mode. You aren't allowed to access the resource. Run your code against a different target, like notepad.exe, and see if the result changes. Also consider using Unicode as opposed to ANSI. Code::Blocks unfortunately defaults to ANSI.

Comment: Which of these should I check in? [image](https://imgur.com/MpuTZey)

Comment: I wasn't referring to the code editor settings, but your project settings. Make sure to have the `_UNICODE` and `UNICODE` preprocessor symbols defined, ideally on the command line. Also make sure that `_MBCS` and `MBCS` are not defined.

Comment: I did [this](https://imgur.com/wRU3Pyy) and still doesn't work.

Comment: That wasn't meant to solve the issue. It's just to help you get a *proper* Windows application written. The recommendation to explicitly or implicitly use Unicode is true for *any* Windows application. And Code::Blocks defaults to ANSI encoding for *any* application type, as if we were still primarily targeting Windows 95.

Answer (score -1):

Well after putting it to Code Blocks, i just changed the _stricmp in the GetModuleBaseAddress function to strcmp also this line

```
HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, procId);
```

to this

```
HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, procId);
```

Try this code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
HANDLE _process = NULL;
DWORD pid = 0;
DWORD baseAddr = 0;
bool getID(string process)
{
    HANDLE hHandle = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS,0);
    PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
    entry.dwSize = sizeof(entry);
    do
    {
        if(!strcmp(entry.szExeFile,process.c_str()))
        {
            pid = entry.th32ProcessID;
            CloseHandle(hHandle);
            _process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,false,pid);
            return true;
        }
    } while(Process32Next(hHandle,&entry));
    return false;
}
bool getModuleBaseAddress(string module)
{
    HANDLE hHandle = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE,pid);
    MODULEENTRY32 mentry;
    mentry.dwSize = sizeof(mentry);
    do
    {
        if(!strcmp(mentry.szModule,module.c_str()))
        {
            CloseHandle(hHandle);
            baseAddr = (DWORD)mentry.modBaseAddr;
            return true;
        }
    } while(Module32Next(hHandle,&mentry));
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    while(!getID("popo.exe")) {Sleep(10);}
    while(!getModuleBaseAddress("popo.exe")) {Sleep(10);}
    cout << "PID: " << pid << endl << "Base Address: " << baseAddr;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I changed too and same result - `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`.

Comment: It worked for me, i compiled it as C++11, but you could first check if the processID was correct in the first place, if so, try running it as an admit and compile it for release mode

Comment: PID is correct (checked with Cheat Engine), I compiled it for release mode and ran as admin, still same result.

Comment: @MiłoszTomkiel Try this code, hope it works for you

Comment: line `baseAddr = (DWORD)mentry.modBaseAddr;` makes error `cast from 'BYTE*' {aka 'unsigned char*'} to 'DWORD' {aka 'long unsigned int'} loses precision [-fpermissive]`

Comment: @MiłoszTomkiel it's okay don't worry about this step

Comment: But because of this line it doesn't want to compile.

Comment: @MiłoszTomkiel add this flag -fpremissive to codeblocks using this post:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024111/fpermissive-option-in-codeblocks-where-do-i-put-that-fpermissive-option]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024111/fpermissive-option-in-codeblocks-where-do-i-put-that-fpermissive-option

Comment: Now it does compile but console remains blank, no output.

Comment: Your console remains blank with no output. Why? How are you going to find out. I suggest you debug your program. Do you know what a debugger is? Do you know the basics of debugging. If not, this the perfect chance to learn.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I wrote this function, you can just call it and it will work

Comment: @MiłoszTomkiel like this:

Comment: @aliberro My comment was not addressed to you. It was addressed to the asker of the question. That said, your code appears to lack error checking and leaks handles. So, "just call it and it will work" is hardly the case.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i wasn't focusing on error checking nor on proper handle management, I just wanted to give him a small working code where he can edit it to his needs